# Randomly show a letter on a button, trouble with my objective-c code

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, switch-statement

I am trying to create a program that will randomly show a letter on a button. I hope to be able to click the button (start) and the program will produce a random letter as the title of the button (letter1).

Each time I run this program it crashes immediately:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)start:(id)sender{

int randomNumber = rand() % 25;

switch (randomNumber){
    case 0:
        [letter1 setTitle:@"A" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;
    case 1:
        [letter1 setTitle:@"B" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;
    case 2:
        [letter1 setTitle:@"C" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;
    case 3:
        [letter1 setTitle:@"D" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;
    case 4:
        [letter1 setTitle:@"E" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;
    case 5:
        [letter1 setTitle:@"F" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;
    case 6:
        [letter1 setTitle:@"G" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;
    case 7:
        [letter1 setTitle:@"H" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;
    case 8:
        [letter1 setTitle:@"I" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;
    case 9:
        [letter1 setTitle:@"J" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;
    case 10:
        [letter1 setTitle:@"K" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;
    case 11:
        [letter1 setTitle:@"L" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;
    case 12:
        [letter1 setTitle:@"M" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;
    case 13:
        [letter1 setTitle:@"N" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;
    case 14:
        [letter1 setTitle:@"O" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;
    case 15:
        [letter1 setTitle:@"P" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;
    case 16:
        [letter1 setTitle:@"Q" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;
    case 17:
        [letter1 setTitle:@"R" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;
    case 18:
        [letter1 setTitle:@"S" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;
    case 19:
        [letter1 setTitle:@"T" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;
    case 20:
        [letter1 setTitle:@"U" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;
    case 21:
        [letter1 setTitle:@"V" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;
    case 22:
        [letter1 setTitle:@"W" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;
    case 23:
        [letter1 setTitle:@"X" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;
    case 24:
        [letter1 setTitle:@"Y" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;
    case 25:
        [letter1 setTitle:@"Z" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;
    default:
        [letter1 setTitle:@"&" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;

   }



}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Any help would be Appreciated!!!!

Comment: What's the crash message?

Comment: What is letter1, is it UIButton ?

Comment: Best not to use `rand()`, it is not very random and needs a seed. Instead use `arc4random()` or `arc4random_uniform(bound)` and there is no need to seed.

Comment: is that code a kind of joke...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You did not provide enough information to explain the crash. But you can shorten your code heavily by elimination the switch statement

```
-(IBAction)start:(id)sender
{
    int randomValue = 'A' + arc4random_uniform(('Z' + 1) - 'A');
    [letter1 setTitle: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", randomValue]) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: wow, that was neat. you reduced his code to 2 lines. +1

Comment: Brilliant thanks man. It turned out to be a problem with my connections, but you just saved me a load of time! incredible!

Answer (score 4):

This is not answer to your question but you can simplify your logic as follows,

```
-(IBAction)start:(id)sender{
    int randomNumber = 65 + arc4random() % 27;
    NSString *letter =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",randomNumber];
    if(randomNumber==91) //Fixed at 91 as your switch loop default case
        [letter1 setTitle:@"&" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    else
        [letter1 setTitle:letter forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: Since you are providing better practice it is better to use `arc4random_uniform(upper_bound)` than the mod operator, this eliminated bias. Ex: `int randomNumber = 65 + arc4random_uniform(27);`

Answer (score 3):

If you're using xib or storyboard, there's possibly something wrong with your connection. Check all your connections(IBOutlet and IBAction) in you xib or storyboard file.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what Janak Said, this is not an answer to your problem until we know what the error is but you can simplify your code.

```
// NSString to ASCII
NSString *string = @"A";
int asciiCode = [string characterAtIndex:0]; // 65

// ASCII to NSString
int asciiCode = 65;
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", asciiCode]; // A
```